# Regex not interworking with mysqli

Tags: php, regex, mysqli

I have the following php code:

```
//Usual mysqli stuff before here --> works

while($post = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $post_text = (string)$post['post_text'];

    $regex = "/(" . (string)$some_var . " - )(.*?)( [A-Z]{4})/";
}

echo $post_text . "<br />";

echo $regex . "<br />";

preg_match($regex, $post_text, $matches);

echo count($matches);
```

Unfortunately I don't get any results back, even though my regex seems to work with this tool here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

I also tried to put the result manually in a string like this:

```
$my_string = "blablablablabla - proper stuff where the regex will find smth"
```

Using this string, the code works, but just not with the string I get back from the db. What am I doing wrong here?

Thx in advance.

Comment: `$some_var` is defined where? or is that a pseudo variable?

Comment: Before - but it is defined - it is not empty. So as I said - everything works as long as I define the string manually (by printing out the mysqli result on the screen and putting it in a string inside the code).

Comment: what does error checking (PHP/MySQL) produce and var_dump?

Comment: Not an answer, but may be helpful: MySQL does provide [regular expression matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) so you could just extend your query to include a regex.

Comment: var_dump shows that $post_text has all the stuff in it, it should have.
And no errors whatsoever.

Comment: You are in a WHILE loop but you are setting SCALAR variables inside the loop i.e. Overwriting the same variable again and again **Dodgie** Or is the while loop unnecessary as you only get one result from the query???

Comment: The loop is not necessary - removed it now. I will just get one result from the db in all cases. Still the same issue though...

Comment: Do you see the data for the 2 `echo` statements?

Comment: I assume you have tried changing `echo count($matches);` to `print_r($matches);`

Answer (score 0):

Made it work myself. Problem was that the string contained new lines so I am running now the following regex on the stuff received from the db:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $post_text)
```

Comment: Was the `.*?` suppose to match the new lines? If so add the `s` modifier and your regex will work as expected; no need for replacement. Providing an example that others can reproduce the issue with always helps. Unknown strings with regex questions are almost impossible to answer.